# map function in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

i want to use a map function to display the label but i get an error like
"Cannot read property 'label' of undefined" in TypeError: Cannot read property 'label' of undefined"

I'm using radio-buttons-react-native to do this. it has an option: data and it accepts an array of data. This is how it works. So for my code, the right way is to do this `data = {data}`. The reason why I want to use the map function is because I want to get the data from my server side. and it seems nothing is working

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  useState
} from 'react';
import {
  Button,
  View,
  Text,
  Image,
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
} from 'react-native';
import RadioButtonRN from 'radio-buttons-react-native';
import {
  Card,
  Title
} from 'react-native-paper';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([{
      label: 'data 1'
    },
    {
      label: 'data 2'
    },
  ]);

  const [SecondData, setSecondData] = useState([{
      label: 'data 5'
    },
    {
      label: 'data 6'
    },
    {
      label: 'data 7'
    },
    {
      label: 'data 8'
    },
  ]);

  const keeper = data.map((item) => { <
    Text > {
      item.label
    } < /Text>
    console.log(item.label)
  })

  return ( <
    SafeAreaView >
    <
    ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator >
    <
    View style = {
      {
        marginTop: Constants.statusBarHeight
      }
    } >
    <
    Card mode = "outlined"
    style = {
      {
        borderColor: 'blue',
        padding: 10,
        backgroundColor: '#ccc',
      }
    } >
    <
    Card.Content >
    <
    Title > SRC PRESIDENT < /Title> <
    /Card.Content> <
    RadioButtonRN data = {
      keeper
    }
    selectedBtn = {
      (e) => console.log(e)
    }
    icon = { < Icon name = "stop-circle"
      size = {
        25
      }
      color = "#2c9dd1" / >
    }
    /> <
    /Card>

    <
    Card mode = "outlined"
    style = {
      {
        borderColor: 'blue',
        marginTop: 20,
        padding: 10,
        backgroundColor: '#ccc',
      }
    } >
    <
    Card.Content >
    <
    Title > GENERAL SECRETARY < /Title> <
    /Card.Content> <
    RadioButtonRN data = {
      SecondData
    }
    selectedBtn = {
      (e) => console.log(e)
    }
    icon = { < Icon name = "check-circle"
      size = {
        25
      }
      color = "#2c9dd1" / >
    }
    /> <
    /Card> <
    /View> <
    /ScrollView> <
    /SafeAreaView>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all your implementation of.map is wrong it will not work in react.
I guess it should return the jsx like this.
eg.

```
const keeper = data.map((item)=>(<Text>{item.label}</Text>))
```

and from this error msg **"TypeError: Cannot read property 'label' of undefined"**

it means the RadioButtonRN component requires an array of object data with label property.
and here you are passing jsx inside the array. so it will not work.

so I would suggest you instead of mapping over this data and passing jsx just pass a plain object with label property.

you need to create a state in hook and fetch data (use promise or async/await) and update this state.
and your updated state data will go inside RadioButtonRN component.

use conditional rendering to hide data while fetching or pass some default entries

Comment: Yes, I've been able to solve it.
In my real code, I mapped the data I got from my server-side, and then passed in the label property and that was it. thanks